# How to count number of occurrences of IP address in CloudWatch log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Let's say I have a cloud-watch log that looks like this:

[image]

The IP on the most left-hand side represents where the request comes from.

Is it possible to list the number of occurrences of each IP in a time range that I specified?

I mean I want to create data which look like this:

```
time range: 2019-06-02 00:00:00 - 2019-06-04 13:00:00
number of occurrences of `172.31.13.80`: 130
number of occurrences of `172.31.25.110`: 112
number of occurrences of `172.31.8.124`: 99
number of occurrences of `172.31.8.121`: 86
```

It seems that [CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) can do something similar to what I want. But I haven't figured out how to do this with Insights.

Does anyone know how to count the number of occurrences of each of the IP?

Comment: Insights provides the [parse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) function, which would let you pull out the fields using regular expressions, but it's not well documented.

Comment: However, is this really what you want to do? Based on your other question, I'm assuming that this is an access log from your behind-the-ELB app-server(s). Which means that those IP addresses are the ELB nodes, _not_ the actual remote clients. Is this really what you want? (I can't imagine any case where I would care about that information, but you may have one) I find that it's far more useful to analyze the [load balancer access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html).

Comment: Yes, this is really what I want to do. I don't want to expose the real IPs of the customers of my company. That's the reason I use the IPs of the load balancers in the question.

Comment: I'll use [the methods here](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-capture-client-ip-addresses/) to upload the clients' IP addresses to CloudWatch.

Comment: Re "I don't want to expose the real IPs": as written, your question doesn't make this clear, and given the prevalence of questions on SO that ask how to do pointless tasks, it's a reasonable assumption that this was one of them.

Answer (score 5):

The query below makes the grouping you need. I saw it [here](https://automato.io/blog/finding-bad-guys-using-aws-cloudwatch-logs-insights.html).

```
fields @timestamp, @message
  | parse @message /(?<@ip>^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})[.]*)/
  | stats count() as requestCount by @ip
  | filter strlen(@ip) > 0
  | sort requestCount desc
```

Answer (score 4):

Identify the IP wherever it is in the log:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
  | parse @message /(?<@ip>^*([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})[.]*)/
  | stats count() as requestCount by @ip
  | sort requestCount desc
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to analyze actual remote IP addresses and you're using an ELB, then it's *far* better to capture the [ELB access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) and analyze those. This will provide the following benefits:

- Access to source request data, including client IP and SSL parameters.
- Timing information, including timing for failed requests.
- No need to write a custom log format that exposes request headers.

[AWS Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/application-load-balancer-logs.html) has pre-built queries for accessing those logs, and Athena's SQL-like query language gives you much more flexibility than CloudWatch Logs Insights. You can also ship the logs to CloudWatch and use Insights (which recognizes the ELB log formats), but this seems like unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

"Elastic Load Balancing logs requests on a best-effort basis. We recommend that you use access logs to understand the nature of the requests, not as a complete accounting of all requests. "

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html

It is worth bearing in mind if accuracy is of high importance and using the ELB logs. I have done some work in the past analysing HTTP access logs with ELB logs and found a fairly substantial difference in the request counts between them (http logs being accurate)